Prove $(g_i ◦ X_i) , i ∈ \{1, . . . , n\}$, are independet random variables (Check my proof please)
Let $(Ω, \mathcal A, \Bbb P)$ a probability space,
$n ∈ \Bbb N$ and let  $(R_i, \mathcal R_i), (S_i, \mathcal S_i), i ∈ \{1, . . . , n\}$,measuring spaces.
Let $X_i: Ω → R_i, i ∈ \{1, . . . , n\}$, independet random variables and $g_i: R_i → S_i, i ∈ \{1, . . . , n\}$, measuring functions.
Show: $(g_i ◦ X_i)
, i ∈ \{1, . . . , n\}$, are independet random variables.
To show that $(g_i \circ X_i)$, for $(i \in \{1, \ldots, n\})$, are independent random variables, we need to demonstrate that their joint distribution function is the product of their marginal distribution functions.
Let $(Y_i = g_i \circ X_i)$. Then the joint distribution function of $(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n)$ is given by:
$[P(Y_1 \leq y_1, Y_2 \leq y_2, \ldots, Y_n \leq y_n)]$
Since $(Y_i = g_i \circ X_i)$, we can rewrite this as:
$[P(g_1 \circ X_1 \leq y_1, g_2 \circ X_2 \leq y_2, \ldots, g_n \circ X_n \leq y_n)]$
Because the $(X_i)$ are independent random variables, the events $(g_i \circ X_i \leq y_i)$ are independent of each other for $(i = 1, \ldots, n)$. This means that the joint distribution function of $(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n)$ can be expressed as the product of their marginal distribution functions:
$[P(Y_1 \leq y_1, Y_2 \leq y_2, \ldots, Y_n \leq y_n) = P(Y_1 \leq y_1) \cdot P(Y_2 \leq y_2) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(Y_n \leq y_n)]$
Since this holds for all $(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n), the (Y_i = g_i \circ X_i)$ are independent random variables.
